# Why is Git branch deleted on remote resurrected another day?

Tags: git, gitblit

I have renamed a local branch, deleted the same on remote, pushed the new name to remote and set the tracking like this:

```
git checkout my_branch
git branch -m my_branch feature/my_branch         # rename
git push origin :my_branch                        # delete on remote
git push --set-upstream origin feature/my_branch  # push and set tracking
```

I've done this for 20+ branches (via a script) and there were no errors.

Contributors did `git fetch --prune` and had updated their local branches (renamed and set new tracking branch).

A day after (on Friday), without any new commit being pushed, the old `origin/my_branch` reappeared **on the same commit** as the `origin/feature/my_branch`. There was no new commit & push that someone could have done by using the old tracking branch. So, I have deleted `origin/my_branch`.

Yet again today (after the weekend) the `origin/my_branch` reappeared **on the same old commit** (dated to Thursday) as `origin/feature/my_branch` is on.

I don't see how and why Git (garbage collector) could resurrect the deleted branch, but possibly the reason is at **Gitblit** (which handles my remote administration) side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense unless one of the following is the responsible

- Some else on your team is pushing this branch again
- External code (hook, script, cron etc) is creating this branch.
- It is the default branch defined in `Gitblit` so its being re-created

The common between those all is that someone (person or script) is creating/pushing this code.

---

The most likely to happen is that **Some else on your team is pushing this branch again.**

As for git version <2 when you write `git pull/push` without specifying remote or branch it will `pull/push` all your branches. It was updated on version 2.

---

## Git v2.0 Release Notes

> When "git push [$there]" does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   "matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. No one is pushing the old branch. Gitblit default branch is master. I'm checking Jenkins as there are no other hooks/scripts that touch the repo. I'll get back with the findings.

Comment: Maybe your Jenkins updates version number, or any other file and then execute `git push` when the branch is already checked out so its being pushed again and again.

Comment: What is your Jenkins git version `git --version` is its less the 2 its the most possible option that Jenkins is the one to be blamed.

Comment: My Jenkins project config had an old value for "Check out to specific local branch" (which was refering to `my_branch`). Solution: either update it to a proper branch name (i.e. `feature/my_branch`) or completely remove it (so the checkedout local branch is taken directly from "Branches to build" param value).

Comment: As i thought. Glad to helped you out.